# Update data in Firebase events table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Events table in firebase is a partitioned table. We cannot have DML operations performed on tables containing WildCard in Query.

However, If we want to update the content of all events data what could be the possible solution for it?

Can we use BigQuery scripting to update data of a partitioned table in BigQuery?

I am thinking of something like adding a loop and generate a dynamic table name variable. Then use that variable to update data. However, I am having issue in using variable as table name.

From initial R&D: Absence of scripting and limited DML operations were the reason for it not being possible earlier. But now that we have both features are we able to do it?

Comment: what would be the specific tasks you would like to have done by the script?

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa I logged wrong event param value for some firebase events and I want to update the value for them to correct them and have them synced

Comment: So you want to go through all of your tables and have one value updated?

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa Yes,  for a particular event in all partitioned tables of event

Comment: I have tried by directly using UPDATE statement but one cannot use DML to change multiple wildcard tables. (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) I also tried scripting but one cannot inject declared variables as sql object identifiers (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery_query_params_named-web) What you could do is have a python /java script generate each query and use the cli-library in order to send them

Comment: Ref Update that makes sense.
Ref scripting, I was betting on that solution, so it isnt supported ?
Ref custom script, yeah that would be my last resort.  

Thanks @AlbertAlbesa